# How can I redesign my code to avoid nested classes in python?

Tags: python, class, oop

Suppose I have three classes: Outer, Inner1 and Inner2. Inner1 and Inner2 both need to access
data members from Outer, but apparently it isn't possible to access data from Outer if Inner1 and Inner2 are nested in Outer. Any ideas for how I should redesign this?

More info:
Each instance of Outer is associated with multiple instances of Inner1 and Inner2. Inner1 represents a point on a curve (the curve is Outer) and Inner2 represents the "numbers" that are the x,y coordinates of Inner2. They all share a piece of data, the prime modulus (and Inner1 needs info on the parameters of the curve).

I would prefer that each instance of Inner1 and Inner2 didn't have to carry around an Outer.

Comment: Pass in the instance of `Outer` to the inner classes?

Comment: Why do you need to nest the classes in the first place?

Comment: In Python, unlike Java, nested classes have no associated instance of the outer class and therefore no magic way to access data from the outer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, unlike Java, nested classes have no associated instance of the outer class and therefore no magic way to access data from the outer class.

One way to achieve this is by making `Inner1` and `Inner2` keep a reference to an instance of `Outer`, and to use that reference to access the data. While you are at it, it might be worth considering whether there is any benefit to nesting the classes; perhaps it might be cleaner to have them live alongside one another.

Comment: That might work. How do I pass references in Python?